# Given two irrational numbers $a,b$, how many integer solutions exist for $an+b=m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

Given two irrational numbers $a,b\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ how many possible solutions exist to the equation

$$an+b=m$$

where $n,m\in \mathbb Z$.

For example, take $a=\sqrt 2$ and $b=-\sqrt 2$. Then clearly we have solutions at $(n=1,m=0)$.

If $b=ta$ for some $t\in\mathbb Z$ then we have

$$an+ta=a(t+n)=m$$

and since the LHS must be irrational for all $n\ne t$ we can say that there exists only one unique solution at $(n=-t,m=0)$.

Is there some general way to count the number of allowed combinations of $n,m$ for all possible $a,b$? My conjecture is that there is $1$ allowed solution to the equation for each and any $a,b$.

Comment: Your conjecture must be false. Fix an irrational number $a$. If $an+b=m$, then $b=m-an$ can only take a countable number of values; so the set of $b$'s for which the equation has no solution is uncountable.

Comment: There's usually no solutions. For example, no integers $n, m$ satisfy $\pi n + \sqrt{2} = m$.

Comment: To denote set removal use `\setminus`, not `/`.

Comment: @TonyK I agree. Then is there some condition on a,b which could be given to specify whether the equation has 0 or 1 solutions?

Answer (score 2):

There is at most one solution. Suppose $m_1-an_1=m_2-an_2$, then we get $m_1-m_2=a(n_1-n_2)$. The RHS is irrational if $n_1\ne n_2$, the LHS is integral. Thus we get $n_1=n_2,m_1=m_2$. We may have zero solutions, like $a=\sqrt3,b=\pi$.

Note that we get a solution iff $\exists n,m\in\Bbb Z|b=m+an$, i.e. $b\in\Bbb Z[a]$.

Comment: what does $\mathbb Z[a]$ mean here?

Comment: @Cameron  $\Bbb Z[a]$ is the set of numbers of the form $m+na,m,n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Does it have a name, or is it something you just defined? I wonder if there is some other way to represent this set.

Comment: @Cameron When $a$ is irrational of the type $\sqrt d$ where $d$ is a square free integer, the set $\Bbb Z[a]$ forms a ring and is called the set of Quadratic integers. In particular, when $d=-1,a=i$ it is called the ring of Gaussian integers. You can search those up: I have taken the set definition and used it for a general irrational number (note that it is no longer a ring).